# Issue with DateTime extract from SQLite Database C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datetime

I have a very freaky mistake...

I have two narrow-equals class, to extract data from sqlite Databases

I save dates as DATETIME in two SQLite databases.
My first, contains this method to load datas

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            string CommandText = "select ID,Name,Solde,Last_Update from Comptes";
            sql_cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Compte compte = new Compte();
                compte.ID = reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                compte.Nom = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                compte.Solde = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Solde"));
                string to = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Last_Update"));
                DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Last_Update")),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                compte.Last_Update = dt;
                this.Comptes.Add(compte);

            }
            sql_con.Close();
        }
```

The second one:

```
private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql_con.Close();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            string CommandText = "SELECT ID,Montant,ID_Emetteur,ID_Recepteur,Description,Date FROM Mouvements";
            sql_cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Mouvement mouvement = new Mouvement();
                mouvement.ID = reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                mouvement.Montant=reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Montant"));
                mouvement.ID_Emetteur=reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID_Emetteur"));
                mouvement.ID_Recepteur=reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID_Recepteur"));
                mouvement.Description=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Description"));
                String out_date = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Date"));
                try
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(out_date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                this.Mouvements.Add(mouvement);

            }
            sql_con.Close();
        }
```

The first method works, but the second gives me an exception near the try catch.
Format are exactly the same.

[image: A Debugger Capture here]

Hope someone will be able to help me !

Comment: What said the exception ?

Comment: Why are you getting the column out as string and then parsing it?

Comment: Because the GetDateTime method doesn't work for me. An exception happenned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use 24-hour time you need to use HH in your format string. hh is for 12-hour time and the supplied time is > 12, so an exception is thrown. This will work.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(out_date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```